# Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda5' failed. This is a fatal error

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, windows-7, grub2

I apologize in advance for my bad english.
I was trying to dual boot Windows 7 and Kubuntu 11.10, and i get this error 'Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda5' failed. This is a fatal error.'. every time when i try install GRUB on boot partition.Tried this on my desktop and laptop and always get this error.
Hope anyone can help.Thanks!

Comment: It might be this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/976027

Answer (score 3):

Grub is installed on the hard drive, not on the partition. I'm assuming you want to create a seperate partition to mount on /boot, but grub-install should be used on a drive (/dev/sda in this particular case), not on a partition.

As long as you set everything right (mountpoints, that is), grub-install will automatically detect your settings and adjust itself accordingly.

Comment: In [this](http://lifehacker.com/5531037/how-to-triple-boot-your-mac-with-windows-and-linux-no-boot-camp-required) lifeHacker article it says: "change the device for boot loader installation to the same partition on which you installed Linux (in the above case, /dev/sda4)." So they are wrong?

Answer (score 1):

ok do this: with a live cd

```
   sudo fdisk -l
```

to know where is installed you linux

```
   sudo mount /dev/sdaX/ mnt
```

X is where your kubuntu is installed

then

```
   sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda
```

then reboot normally and then

do this

```
   sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I didnt aks this question well, this error happens during Kubuntu 11.10 install on a free space.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it worked for me:

Choose **Try Ubuntu** without installation

The system boots up with desktop on which there is **Install Ubuntu** copy the command of this icon (right click - properties - command)

Now open a terminal and do

```
sudo bash
```

run the copied command from here (I think the command was as below)

```
ubiquity %k ubuntu-desktop
```

And success.

I was installing 11.10 x64 on my desktop considering dual-boot where Windows XP x64 is already installed. I had kept provision of a boot partition in advance. The installation order does not matter.

```
/sda1 /boot 260M (primary)

/sda2 win-xp     (primary)
..
(2 more logical partitions)
..
/sda7 /    10g
/sda8 swap
```

While I was trying to install Ubuntu, I was getting fatal error while installing grub on /dev/sda1. I tried on /dev/sda without success.

Then I employed to run the installation from root shell. It worked.